# ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor . cannot connect to oracle 11g?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have installed Oracle 11.2 expression edition and it was running fine. All of a sudden when I opened it next time, I get this error - nothing has been changed from my end.

This is my `tnsnames.ora` file and my `listener.ora` file

tnsnames.ora:

```
XE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = DESKTOP-JAS1O0C)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
    )
  )

EXTPROC_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = PLSExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )

ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA = 
  (DESCRIPTION = 
    (ADDRESS_LIST = 
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1)) 
    ) 
    (CONNECT_DATA = 
      (SID = CLRExtProc) 
      (PRESENTATION = RO) 
    ) 
  )
```

listener.ora:

```
SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = PLSExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
    )
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = DESKTOP-JAS1O0C)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )

DEFAULT_SERVICE_LISTENER = (XE)
```

Error:

[image]

Comment: Are all the Oracle services running?

Comment: yes Oracleservicexe and oraclexeTNSListener are running

Answer (score 0):

For scenarios like this, the `alert_<SID>.log` is your friend. Here you can diagnose the database health.

Your Windows Service can be `running`, but your database can be in any of these modes: `stopped | nomount | mount | open`

```
%ORACLE_BASE%\diag\rdbms\xe\XE\trace\alert_XE.log
```

Best of luck!

Comment: I tried to un install and re install but im getting the error as -Status : Failure -Test failed: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor